# jQuery UI Draggable 'stop' event called too many times?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a feeling I'm either misunderstanding the 'stop' event  or not doing it right, but it seems to be called several times while the element is bound to is being dragged.

```
makeAllDragable = function () {
    $(".test-table").draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) { $(this).click(); },
        stop: function (event, ui) { foo() }
    }).click(function () {
        selectTable($(this));
    });
}

foo = function () {
    alert("test");
}
```

In this example foo is called about 30 times, shouldn't is just be when I release the draggable? The jQuery docs don't actually say one where or another though.

Comment: Works properly for me. `.stop()` is called when mouse button is released. http://jsfiddle.net/jRjup/

Comment: The example give me a JS error from the site that says 'console is undefined' form the site so I can't check it out.

Comment: Just comment out the `console` line. I just needed to create `selectTable` so your `click` would have a function to call. http://jsfiddle.net/jRjup/2/

Comment: I just realized the issue, I had the foo() call in the click function as well, which is what causes it to be called every time it's moved. I haven't seen jsfiddle before though, very cool.

Comment: Graham, you should post this as an answer and then select your answer as the accepted one so (1) others can easily find it and (B) you collect the points.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, answered below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the above code I wrote up in my original question was not what i was working with, I actually had foo() called like so:

```
makeAllDragable = function () {
    $(".test-table").draggable({
        start: function (event, ui) { $(this).click(); },
        stop: function (event, ui) { foo() }
    }).click(function () {
        foo(); /*difference here*/
    });
}
```

For whatever reason dragging it raises the click() function repeatedly when the function is also present in the stop() event. At least that's what appears to be happening on the surface at least.